# How to change the input language in C# code?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writting a wpf application using C# (VS2010) and when my application runs , the input language is taken from the system input language which is English.

I want my application to change the input language automatically without having to press (`Shift + Alt`)

Can you tell me how to do that please?

Another question, can I change the timezone in my system using my application too?

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to change the input language for your application, look at [InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.currentinputlanguage.aspx)

Or if you want to change the system default input language look at the [SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947%28VS.85%29.aspx) function with the `SPI_SETDEFAULTINPUTLANG` flag.

Regarding the time zone, there is the [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) class to get out information but to set it you'd need to use the [SetTimeZoneInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724944.aspx) function.

Comment: How can I do it in WPF application?

Comment: @yadavr I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. The question is regarding doing it in a WPF application.

Answer (score 4):

I know this topic is quite old one, but should you've got here from the Google by a some search request like "wpf switch keyboard" (as have I)
You should definitely try the special WPF class InputLanguageManager:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputlanguagemanager.aspx
Especially pay attention to the one of its attached properties called InputLanguage. In most cases its all what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You must use this function:

```
public static void lang(string lge)
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo TypeOfLanguage = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(lge);
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(TypeOfLanguage);
}
```

and when you call this function the parameter lge must be the label of desired language 
for example "ar-dz" for Algerian Arabic language or "fr-fr" for French language.

Answer (score 0):

First add

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Then write after InitializeComponent(); this code

```
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(Application.CurrentCulture);
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(new CultureInfo("ar-EG"));
```